# Cucumber (Gherkin) Full support extension for VS Code was unable to find step for

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber

I'm using VS Code and Cucumber extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete&ssr=false#overview doesn't work.
This is my settings.json in .vscode folder:

```
{
"cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
    "src/step_definitions/*.js",
],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "src/features/*feature",
"cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
"cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinValidation": true,
"cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
"cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true,
// "cucumberautocomplete.pages": {
//     "users": "test/features/page_objects/users.storage.js",
//     "pathes": "test/features/page_objects/pathes.storage.js",
//     "main": "test/features/support/page_objects/main.page.js"
// },
"cucumberautocomplete.skipDocStringsFormat": true,
"cucumberautocomplete.formatConfOverride": {
    "And": 3,
    "But": "relative",
},
"cucumberautocomplete.onTypeFormat": true,
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true,
    "other": true
},
"cucumberautocomplete.gherkinDefinitionPart": "(Given|When|Then)\\(",
"cucumberautocomplete.stepRegExSymbol": "'"
}
```

And this is what I have added to settings.json of VS Code:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 0
}
```

When in my feature file I get the message for each line:
"Was unable to find step for "Given I am on the dashboard page"cucumberautocomplete"

Can someone help to resolve this issue and make it work for VS Code?

Kind regards,
mismas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it finally worked when I:

I. deleted .vscode/settings.json (including the folder)
II. added following in global settings.json of Visual Sudio Code (the one in Users etc directory)

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"gherkin-autocomplete.featuresPath": "src/features",
"cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
    "src/step_definitions/*.js",
],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "src/features/*feature",
}
```

III. restarted VS Code

Either is something wrong with the plugin => meaning they didn't implemented as they think it should work or documentation is out dated ...

Comment: That was exactly that, for some reason the user settings results a buggy behavior. can someone explain ?

Answer (score 5):

I had to remove the line

```
"cucumberautocomplete.stepRegExSymbol": "'"
```

and then it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove or comment on below line from setting.json

"cucumberautocomplete.stepRegExSymbol": "'"

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Windows10:

1. navigate to %APPDATA%\Code\User (which is VScode config folder)
2. add

   "gherkin-autocomplete.featuresPath": "features",
   "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
   "features/step_definitions/*.js",],
   "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*feature"
3. restart vscode

Answer (score 0):

Download extension in Visual Studio Code

[Snippets and Syntax Highlight for Gherkin (Cucumber)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevejpurves.cucumber)

After you've installed the plugin, go to File -> Preferences -> Settings

In search type Cucumber

[image]

Click Edit in settings.json

In settings.json object add properties (Make sure to adjust the paths to valid ones inside your project):

```
{
  "cucumber.features": ["cypress/integration/**/*.feature"],
  "cucumber.glue": ["cypress/integration/**/*.js", "cypress/support/*.js"],
  "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
    "cypress/support/*.js",
    "cypress/integration/**/*.js"
  ],
  "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "cypress/integration/**/*.feature",
  "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": false,
  "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
  "cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true
}
```

After you've done these two steps make sure to restart you VSC.

Voila!